# Как удалить одинаковые значения в списке ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Подскажите, как удалить одинаковые значения, например 232323 232323 из `ArrayList<String> id_ = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 9):

Если в коллекции необоходимо хранить элементы, которые не должны иметь дубликаты, то в таких случаях используется `Set` или одна из его реализаций.

> **`Set`** – это коллекция уникальных элементов, или коллекция, которая не позволяет хранить одинаковые элементы.

Самый простой способ удалить повторяющиеся элементы - это добавить содержимое в `Set`(что не допустит дублирования), а затем добавить `Set` обратно в `ArrayList`:

```
// помещаем вашу коллекцию в сет
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(id_);

// чистим вашу коллекцию
id_.clear();

// помещаем из коллекции сета обратно в вашу коллекцию,
// которая на данный момент ещё пустая
id_.addAll(set);
```

Но стоит обратить внимание, что при добавлении обратно в `ArrayList`, порядок будет нарушен.

Можно так же использовать `LinkedHashSet` для сохранения порядка.

```
Set<String> s = new LinkedHashSet<>(id_);
```

---

В `Java 8` можно удалить удалить дубликаты с помощью метода `distinct()`.

```
List<Integer> listWithoutDuplicates =
        id_.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно решить данную проблему при использовании `Set`:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(id_);
id_.clear();
id_.addAll(set);
```